# Can we able to get source of 'button click event' in lightning experience(Standard Lightning Page) in apex class called by trigger?

Tags: apex

Example: We have a custom list view action button in lightning experience and I want to check some conditions on button click and before it updates the record. I don't find any other way to check this, but in 'before update trigger' so want to check the source of event in apex before performing the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try overriding list view button with vf page where you can put any custom logic .

```
<apex:page 
    showHeader="false" 
    standardStylesheets="false" 
    sidebar="false" 
    applyHtmlTag="false" 
    applyBodyTag="false" 
    docType="html-5.0"  
    standardController="Account"
    recordSetVar="accounts"
    extensions="CustomController">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't try to override the list view button. I'll try with this approach.